# How to follow the "Knuth license"

Tags: copyright, licensing, knuth

I want to use some of the code from `manfnt.mf`. Perhaps my situation is best summarized by this (draft) commit message (slightly edited to look okay when processed as markdown):

> New file dbend.mf
>
> Copy of http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/knuth/dist/lib/manfnt.mf,
>   which has a modification date of "1989-08-11 11:39:25" listed.
>
> http://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/knuth/dist/lib says that this is
>   under the Knuth License (http://ctan.org/license/knuth):
>
> This software is copyright and you are explicitly granted a
>   license which gives you, the “user” of the software, legal
>   permission to copy, distribute and/or modify the software, so   long
>   as if you modify the software then it carry a different   name from
>   the original software.
>
> I have already renamed it preparatory to modifying it.  (I was going
>   to do this regardless of the license because I plan to strip out
>   everything but the "dangerous bend" symbol.)

I'm wondering:

1. Why don't `/usr/share/doc/texlive-base/copyright` or `/usr/share/doc/texlive-base/Licenses.gz` give a license for this file? All I could find was this in the latter:

   ```
   misc:
   texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/misc/*
   texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/misc/*
   texmf-dist/omega/ocp/misc/*
   texmf-dist/omega/otp/misc/*
   texmf-dist/tex/generic/misc/*
   texmf-dist/tex/plain/misc/*
   ```
2. How does CTAN "know" that this license applies? <del>I didn't see anything about this in-tree, either on CTAN or on ftp.cs.stanford.edu ...</del>

   Oh, huh, in checking that I had the right domain just now, I noticed ftp://ftp.cs.stanford.edu/pub/tex/README.KNUTH, which seems to say something at least similar. (`manfnt.mf` is in ftp://ftp.cs.stanford.edu/pub/tex/dist/lib/.)
3. What should I put in the license blurb for my modified file, if I want to (say) CC0 my contributions?

Comment: Where is “this (draft) commit message” from? Please link, if possible, or add info about this.

Comment: @Speravir: my `*magit-edit-log*` buffer in Emacs.  I didn't commit anything yet, but I'm all set to commit a renamed copy of `manfnt.mf`.

Comment: @SamB: Then this is misunderstandable.

Comment: @Speravir: I'm afraid *I* don't understand *your* last comment :-(

Comment: @Speravir: It looks to me as if the OP is providing a draft of a commit message. What other interpretation are you seeing?

Comment: @SamB: Hmm, you and Charles are natural English speakers, I am not. I guess I would have understood this better when you’ve added information from comment into your question: “… this (draft) commit I intend to commit to a renamed copy of `manfnt.mf` …” or how you would write this in your words.

Comment: I'm guessing there's an oversight here which should be reported. In TL 2011 and 2012, I have `texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/misc/manfnt.mf`. Only in TL 2013 does `texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/knuth-lib/manfnt.mf` appear. My guess is that the information has not been updated. This means that, strictly speaking, we have the file with no licence in the TL 2013 distribution... This may be a distro packaging error, though, since I'm not sure licences are in the same location in TL from upstream...

Comment: @cfr: hmm, this is coming from Debian's `texlive-base 2013.20131219-1` package ...

Comment: @SamB Precisely. I'm guessing it is a packaging error. I can't find any equivalent of the lists by licence in my installation of TeX. (Certainly not at the same location.) I'd guess those lists are created by Debian as part of the packaging process and they've not updated them correctly. But that's just a guess.

Comment: concerning misc versus knuth-lib: this was a recent change in TeX Live upstream as consequence of clean up. The license applies independent of where the file is located. Concerning the Debian copyright file: don't take that fully serious. It is half-automatized, outdated, etc. I can and don't want to keep track of each and every file down in Debian/TeX Live, as we are doing this in upstream TeX Live anyway, throwing out non-free files, not including non-free files etc.

Comment: @norbert: I certainly didn't mean to imply you should write it by hand

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i've done some research into the history of the "license" and the file `manfnt.mf`.

this file (current version from 1989) long predates both the creative commons (2001)
and most of the discussion regarding "free" software licenses (although the
free software foundation was formed in 1985).

knuth's original files for fonts do not incorporate license statements; that information
is covered by a separate file.  (explicit license statements have been added to
the derivative files, e.g. type 1, that were produced later, by other developers.)
however, because of knuth's standing, and his many public statements concerning his
intentions with regard to all tex-related software (namely that it can be used freely,
modified to suit one's needs, but -- if changed -- given a new name), this material
has been accepted for inclusion in tex live.  (after all, without tex itself, there
would be no purpose for tex live to exist.)  the reason for the name change
request/requirement is practical -- to avoid the confusion that would ensue if
a "different" file were used instead of the intended one.  (there is already more
than enough confusion when using a different version of a legitimately updated package.)

i passed the question to karl berry, who has considerable experience in this area.
hw suggests the following:

> % This file, dbend.mf, is derived from manfnt.mf, which was
>   % created by Donald Knuth and released under his usual license:
>   % http://www.ctan.org/license/knuth.
>   %
>   % Modifications by xxx to dbend.mf are released to the public domain.

if you choose instead to use CC0, then the CC0 faq on the creative commons site gives the
[recommended text](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/CC0_FAQ) (or go directly to the
[specific url](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/CC0_FAQ#May_I_apply_CC0_to_computer_software.3F_If_so.2C_is_there_a_recommended_implementation.3F) ).

Comment: In case you aren't aware, the CC0 is basically the public domain + a plan B in case that doesn't work in a relevant jurisdiction.